# Looking for a Christmas/Saint Nicholas book

Tags: identification-request

Sorry if this is off-topic.

When I was a child (around 10 so early 90's), my grandparents gave me a book about the history of Santa Clause/Saint Nicholas/other alternate names.

What I recall about the book

- The images were red, black and white. The pages were white, and the text black. There **may** have been some exceptions to this, where the text was red.
- The text was in English
- It was illustrated inside, with Scandanavian-style artwork
- It appeared quite dark/sinister, at least for a young boy
- It was a hardback
- It was relatively thin, at < 100 pages
- It was slightly smaller than A4 in size
- It talked about what Santa would be called in various countries, particularly focused on Scandinavia and Europe. I don't **recall** anything about Santa in North/South America.

I would like to find this book, and ideally acquire a copy, however, I've no idea what it is called.

Does anyone know of a book which meets (and likely exceeds) the above criteria?